# Draggable doesn't save order

Tags: categories, sorting

Someone know why Draggable doesn't save new categories order? I use draggable 1.4.2 with ExpressionEngine 2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

Stemwinder has fix the bug with URLs in 2.8.1

https://github.com/stemwinder/draggable

Comment: Hey thanks for the link. Since 2.8 Draggable hadn't worked for me and I thought it was no longer being developed. Glad someone had updated it - such a handy add-on.